# Set state to initial state in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to know if it's possible to set the state to the initial state values whenever we press back the button in the tabBar ? At the moment, when I leave the tabBar and come back after a few navigation in the app, the infos that the user enter in TextField persist.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You **could** use React hooks to achieve similar results to lifecycle methods in class functions.

The useEffect method runs on component render. You can set the state in there.

```
const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{

   // This will run after 1st render
   setCurrentState(""); 

},[]);
```